# Map layers do not align with each other in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf, geom-sf

Recently, I have been asked to produce a map showing fault lines in Turkey after the unfortunate two earthquakes that took place today. Although I am not an expert in geospatial analysis, I have tried to produce this map with the following code chunk

```
library(elevatr)
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(giscoR)
library(marmap)

# Getting the country's geospatial data

crsLONGLAT <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

get_sf <- function(country_sf, country_transformed) {
  
  country_sf <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(
    year = "2016",
    epsg = "4326",
    resolution = "10",
    country = "Turkey")
  
  country_transformed <- st_transform(country_sf, crs = crsLONGLAT)
  
  return(country_transformed)
}

country_transformed <- get_sf()

# Getting the fault lines data

shapename <- read_sf('gem_active_faults_harmonized.shp') %>%
  st_set_crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

# Producing the map

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = country_transformed) +
  geom_sf(data = shapename, aes(color = "orange", size = 3)) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(26, 45), ylim = c(36, 42)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

As can be seen from the code chunk, my workflow is based on 3 levels. First, getting the county's coordinates, and second getting the active fault lines data, which is available [in this link](https://github.com/GEMScienceTools/gem-global-active-faults)  and lastly merging these two datasets to produce the desired output. However, in the output produced as a result of this code, the layers do not seem align with each other. Therefore, do you have any suggestions to fix that problem? Thank you for your attention beforehand.

[image]

Comment: What's the CRS of your `gem_active_faults_harmonized.shp` file? You probably don't need to use `st_set_crs()` on it, because the shapefile should already contain the correct CRS info. If you need to change it to match the CRS of your other spatial layer, use `st_transform()`, not `st_set_crs()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map looks fine to me. Here is another way to make it.

Get the data

```
f <- 
"/vsicurl/https://github.com/GEMScienceTools/gem-global-active-faults/raw/master/geopackage/gem_active_faults_harmonized.gpkg"

library(terra)
flts <- vect(f)
wrld <- geodata::world(path=".")
wrld <- crop(wrld, ext(25, 45, 30, 43)+5)
epic <- cbind(37.203, 38.024)
```

With base-plot

```
plot(wrld, xlim=c(25, 45), ylim=c(30, 43), col=gray(0.95), back="azure", las=1)
lines(flts, col="red")
points(epic, pch=20, cex=2)
```

[image]

With ggplot

```
library(tidyterra)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_spatvector(data = wrld) +
  geom_spatvector(data = flts, color = "red", size = 3) +
  geom_spatvector(data = vect(epic, crs=crs(flts))) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(25, 45), ylim = c(30, 43)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

And your approach with sf can be reduced to

```
library(sf)
country <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country = "Turkey")
faults <- sf::read_sf('gem_active_faults_harmonized.shp')
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = country) +
  geom_sf(data = faults, color = "orange", size = 3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(26, 45), ylim = c(36, 42)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

(using the shapefile, sf does not want to read the gpkg file).